# jQuery Mobile: How to submit a form via ajax dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I currently have a form with a 'select' input in it. When the user selects an option, I want the form to submit automatically.

Here's my current code:

```
<form method="get">
    <select name="category" data-native-menu="false" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Currently, when a user selects one of the options, the form is submitted. However, it is submitted *without* ajax.

So, is there a jQuery Mobile specific function I have to call to get the form to submit via ajax, as forms by default do when they are submitted using a submit button?

---

**Edit:**

Here's the solution I found:

```
<form action='myPage' method="get" id='myForm'>
    <select name="category" data-native-menu="false" onchange="$.mobile.changePage( 'myPage', {type: 'get', data: $('form#myForm').serialize()} );">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not use the built-in FormData?

Comment: I don't really know what you're referring to. Could you explain what FormData is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to get the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) object:

```
var formData = $('form')[0].getFormData()
```

Alternatively, check out the [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize) doc from jQuery's documentation:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    alert($(this).serialize());
    return false;
});
```

The return false prevents the form submit handler from firing. Instead of alert, do something with the data (stick it in you ajax handler, for example).

Edit:

The OP said the problem was solved by reading this page: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: Although I could indeed do something with this, I believe you might have misunderstood my post. Currently the framework I'm using, [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), automatically submits all forms to the specified page using ajax, and the returns the response page, which is then dynamically loaded into the DOM of the current page. So that I don't have to re-create this entire process manually, I'm really just looking for some function call pre-existing in the JQuery Mobile code that allows me to submit the form, just as a submit button might do.

Comment: The question made it sound like it wasn't submitting via ajax, but the page was reloading. Perhaps you could try `$('form').submit()`

Comment: Actually, after using the serialize() function as a keyword searching in the jQuery Mobile docs, I was able to find a bit of code that allows me to do such a thing! For anyone else that has the problem, the code is located under the [changePage](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/api/methods.html) section. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
<form action='myPage' method="get" id='myForm'>
    <select name="category" data-native-menu="false" onchange="$(this.form).trigger('submit');">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```